# Cannot invoke an internal method within a dll

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I have this class in a ddl file:

```
namespace A
{
    internal class PW
    {
        static PW()
        {
            //code
        }

        internal static string G(int num)
        {
            //more code
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PW_tester
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            MethodInfo method = typeof (PW).GetMethod("G", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] {typeof(int)}, null);     
        }
    }
}
```

I get `null` as value of the method variable.
That is my whole program.

The dll file is referenced in the project and PW class is found.

I know I cannot invoke it with

```
A.PW.G(0);
```

But I will get cannot access internal class/method error which at least proves that the program is aware of its existence.

How do I call the `G` method?

Comment: Is the class `PW` internal? How can you reference it via `typeof(PW)` if it is internal?

Comment: Can you examine the dll file with `ILSpy`?

Comment: I did, that is how I know the names and what I'm looking for. I need to know the result of PW.G(51567). And since it's using some of the dlls resources and some other dll specific data, I need it to run in its native habitat, so to speak.

Comment: Try removing the `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` flag

Comment: Didn't help, still null.

Comment: Does it work when in the same project? Is it only when it crosses AppDomain that `GetMethod()` returns `null`?

Comment: That's the problem. The method uses some resources from the dll and some of it's names so it doesn't work standalone. Providing that data manually returned invalid results so I'm forced to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes an `int` parameter, not a `string`.

Try this:

```
var method = typeof(PW).GetMethod(
    "G",
    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(int) }, //parameter is of type int
    null);
```

This will obtain a `MethodInfo` that presents the method type information. Here is how you can use it to invoke the method:

```
var result = (string)method.Invoke(null, new object[] {5}); //pass 5 as the int parameter
```

Comment: Even with that change, the return is still null. Invoking it would get me NullReferenceException.

Comment: I tested the code locally and it works. Of course I changed the class to `public` because if it is internal, then you cannot even reference it via `typeof(PW)`. Since it does not work for you, I think that the real code that you have is different from the one in your question.

Comment: It says internal and that seems to be the problem. Is there any other way I can invoke the method?

Comment: In the question, you say that you use `typeof(PW)`? Is this the case? Does it even compile?

Comment: The code I wrote compiles and executes without an error. But the MethodInfo I get is null. The type (class) lists only 4 methods (toString, Equals, etc).

Comment: So class `PW` is internal? And you can compile `typeof(PW)` in a project that is different than the project/dll where `PW` is defined?

Comment: Yes. I referenced the dll in the project. The autocomplete sees both the class and the method, but doesn't compile if I try accessing them directly. And what I tried doesn't seem to see the method. It sees the class though.

Comment: Is there a chance that you are referencing the wrong `PW` class? maybe there is another one. The reason I am saying this is that you cannot reference internal classes directly. Try to create a a test project just to test this.

Comment: There is no other PW class. Isn't the whole point of reflections to surpass hierarchy (among other things)?

Comment: Yes. But not through `typeof(PW)`. This piece of code cannot compile if `PW` is internal.

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe it doesn't compile for you because you didn't reference it?

Answer (score 0):

The class being `internal` cannot be reflected outside the `AppDomain`.

This is the result:

[image: scr]

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha94aebs.aspx

Edit 1

---

I was able to get to it using manual loading of the assembly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var asy = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"<path>\A.dll");
        var pw = asy.GetTypes()[0];
        var method = pw.GetMethod("G", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Static);
    }
}
```

Comment: You you are correct, I've been using the same project for a while trying different things and I had my own PW class the code was accessing that I didn't notice until now. That still doesn't help me access it if there is any way to do so.

Comment: Once you have access to `PW` it should work fine. The problem is that `typeof(PW)` returns `null`. So you need to look for types in `A.dll` using `Assembly.GetTypes()`

Comment: @Karlovsky120, please update your question to reflect your new findings.

Comment: Well I tried `var asy = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();` and the assembly `A` does not appear in the loaded assemblies, even though it is included in the references.